# Generic Method, generic return type mismatch

Tags: java, generics

The following Java code will not compile.

```
public <DO extends ServerDataObject> ProxyDataObject<DO> convertToProxy(Class<DO>   doClass) throws Exception{
    if(getId()==0)return null;
    ProxyDataObject<DO> proxy = (ProxyDataObject<DO>) doClass.newInstance();
    proxy.setID(getId());
    return proxy;
}

public interface ProxyDataObject<DO extends ServerDataObject> extends ServerDataObject, DataTransferInterface {

public void setID(int id);

@Ignore
public String getIDName();
}
```

The following message is given:

> Bound mismatch: The type DO is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter DO extends ServerDataObject of the type ProxyDataObject

This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry there was another ServerDataObject

Comment: Which line is the error refering to?

Answer (score 1):

`doClass` is type `Class<DO>`, so `doClass.newInstance()` has type `DO`. How can you possibly cast this to `ProxyDataObject<DO>`?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. It compiles fine for me with Java 1.6.0_26, albeit with a warning.

The first problem is that your method signature should read either:

```
public <DO extends ServerDataObject> ProxyDataObject<DO> convertToProxy(
        Class<? extends ProxyDataObject<DO>> doClass
    ) throws Exception {
    if(getId()==0)return null;
    ProxyDataObject<DO> proxy = doClass.newInstance();
    proxy.setID(getId());
    return proxy;
}
```

or:

```
public <DO extends ProxyDataObject<?>> DO convertToProxy(Class<DO> doClass) throws Exception{
    if(getId()==0)return null;
    DO proxy = doClass.newInstance();
    proxy.setID(getId());
    return proxy;
}
```

depending on what you actually meant.

Second, DO extends ServerDataObject, not ProxyDataObject. With the inheritance you have defined it is possible for an instance of ServerDataObject to not be a ProxyDataObject. Therefore you get the error you are seeing.